# How to fetch continuous frames in camera2api android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm facing issue regarding Camera2API:
I have created camera app with camera2api and I need to get frame data(bytearray) form camerapreview
with camera2api I have tried

```
val frame =
               Bitmap.createBitmap(
                   mTextureView!!.width,
                   mTextureView!!.height,
                   Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
               )
```

and converted into byte array

```
frame.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream)
byteArray = stream.toByteArray()
```

it's working but taking too much time for conversion

is there any way like camera1API directly get bytearray

```
override fun onPreviewFrame(data : ByteArray, camera: Camera)
```

Comment: I think we need more description to help you. What is the issue? When? The bit of code can be helpful too

Answer (score 0):

You can check the example source code: [link to github](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/kotlinApp/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.kt)

Also as I think CameraX API might interest you, try to check the [Google code lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0)